# IntelliJ reports errors in testng.xml after swtiching from Maven to Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, testng, testng.xml

Since I'v swtitched from Maven to Gradle, IntelliJ reports errors in all my TestNG `.xml` configuration files. It seems to be unable to find location of my custom listeners classes as in attached picture.

[image: xml errors]

It is however, somehow able to provide autocompletion:

[image: autocompletion]

My `build.gradle` mentions that config files are not in root but in `/testng` folder:

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'testng/' + System.getProperty('suiteFile', 'testng.xml') ?: 'testng.xml'
    }

    systemProperties(System.getProperties())
}
```

It's been like that for few months now, I am not sure what can I do about it besides switching off error notifications?

Comment: is `/testng` folder marked as test resources in 'Project Settings | Modules | Sources'?

Comment: @quickfix Now it is, thank you